# Initialising hist function in Julia for use in a loop

Tags: histogram, julia

When I use a loop, to access the variables outside of the loop they need to be initialised before you enter the loop. For example:

```
Y = Array{Int}()
for i = 1:end
    Y = i
end
```

Since I have initialised Y before entering the loop, I can access it later by typing

```
Y
```

If I had not initialised it before entering the loop, typing Y would not have returned anything.

I want to extend this functionality to the output of the 'hist' function. I don't know how to set up the empty hist output before the loop. The only work around I have found is below.

```
yHistData = [hist(DataSet[1],Bins)] 

for j = 2:NumberOfLayers
    yHistData = [yHistData;hist(DataSet[j],Bins)] 
end
```

Now when I access this later on by simply typing

```
yHistData
```

I get the correct values returned to me.
How can I initialise this hist data before entering the loop without defining it using the first value of the list I'm iterating over?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do here. Why do you need the loop and what are you looping through? If you want the histogram bins you can just do `hist(vector, bins)` to get the slices and counts.

Comment: you can initialize it with a array of size 1 and a zero `hist(zeros(1),Bins)`, still is not clear what you want to do.

Comment: you can init it with an empty array like your first example, say `yHistData = Array{Any,1}()`

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. The loop was a simplified example and not the real code. I need to store the output of the hist of many different data sets that I iterate over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a loop like follows:

```
yHistData = []
for j = 1:NumberOfLayers
    push!(yHistData, hist(DataSet[j], Bins))
end
```

`push!` modifies the array by adding the specified element to the end. This increases code speed because we do not need to create copies of the array all the time. This code is nice and simple, and runs faster than yours. The return type, however, is now `Array{Any, 1}`, which can be improved.

Here I have typed the array so that the performance when using this array in the future is better. Without typing the array, the performance is sometimes better and sometimes worse than your code, depending on `NumberOfLayers`.

```
yHistData = Tuple{FloatRange{Float64},Array{Int64,1}}[]
for j = 1:NumberOfLayers
    push!(yHistData, hist(DataSet[j], Bins))
end
```

Assuming `length(DataSet) == NumberOfLayers`, we can use anonymous functions to simplify the code even further:

```
yHistData = map(data -> hist(data, Bins), DataSet)
```

This solution is short, easy to read, and very fast on Julia 0.5. However, this version is not yet released. On 0.4, the currently released version, the performance of this version will be slower.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have been testing this out and can't figure out how to initialise it in general cases. For example I have a variable X that I know is an Array{Float64,2} but I don't know what the dimensions of the array will be inside the loop so I can't specify these beforehand. When I try your method above but replace the [ ] with Array{Float64,2} for X (which is not histogram data) and then enter the loop, I get the error message that there is a dimension mismatch. Is there a way of initialising X before entering the loop to let it take any dimensions once it is in the loop?

Comment: @user3061923 Could you give more information about what you mean by dimension? Do you mean that your array might be 3-dimensional or 4-dimension, or do you mean that it could take various different sizes?

Comment: My array that gets created in the loop might be 3x40 or 3x30 for eg depending on the number of data points I get (either 30 or 40 or any other number of points). BUT, within the loop, if it is 3x30 for eg, then each iteration will always be 3x30 while the loop is executing. I know I could find out the length 3x30 before the loop and use this information to define the empty arrray size to avoid this dimension mismatch problem but I'd rather understand how to avoid having to do this - how to initialise an array before hand without having to specify the exact size for eg Array{Float64,2}(3,30).

Comment: @user3061923 So you want a vector (one-dimensional array) of matrices (two dimensional arrays)? Then initializing to `Array{Float64,2}[]` will work. The size of the array is not stored in the type.

Comment: Yes exactly, that works perfectly. Thank you SO much.